# Could not find or load main class in java

Tags: java, batch-file, program-entry-point

Following is a batch file written to run the at&t ARO data analyzer.

```
@setlocal

if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if "%_JAVA%" == "" set _JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
goto run

:noJavaHome
if "%_JAVA%" == "" set _JAVA=java.exe

:run
"%_JAVA%" -cp "%~dp0..\lib\*" -Xms100m -Xmx1024m com.att.aro.main.Launch
```

the "lib" directory contains several executable jar files. when i run the above batch file I get an error as follows.

```
   Error: Could not find or load main class D:\Industrial Training\ARO-master\ARODa
taAnalyzer\bin\..\lib\ddmlib.jar
```

The applications main entry point is at com.att.aro.main.Launch. This class is included in a jar filed name ARO.jar in the lib directory. But java is unable to find this class due to some reason. What has gone wrong here?

Note: when I edit the last line of the batch file as follows, the application runs without any error.

```
"%_JAVA%" -cp "%~dp0..\lib\*; \classes\*" -Xms100m -Xmx1024m com.att.aro.main.Launch
```

Comment: What happens if there is no white space in your directory names anymore?

Comment: Are you asking me to change the directory name Industrial training?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

The `-cp` option doesn't do what you think here. You're thinking it's including all the jar files in that lib folder, but it isn't. If you put \lib on your classpath, then any class that it finds in there will be loaded (which is why when you put the /classes directory in it, it works. There's a com/ directory there, and so on to the class). That doesn't work for JAR files.

What you need to do in your script is list all the jar files you want to include and in a for loop, add them one by one to the classpath. It's kinda weird, but I suspect it has something to do with making sure you get what you asked for and not mistakenly load some JAR file you didn't want.

Something along those lines on Windows:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH="
for /R %~dp0..\lib %%j in (*.jar) do (
  set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%j
)
set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!"
echo !CLASSPATH!
```

If you don't want to get too crazy, you can use this option:

`-Djava.ext.dirs=%~dp0..\lib`

And just let the JVM scoop it all up. Of course it only works if your app doesn't already need that property for something else. I'm not familiar with ARO.

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html: "As a special convenience, a class path element containing a basename of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR"